# stdio.h not found when compiling fsevent on OS X

Tags: macos, rubygems

Got this when trying to install the rb-fsevent gem:

```
fsevent/fsevent_watch.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Run this command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/
```

And then compilation will work.

Comment: What's happening behind here? Having some issues running this as well (invalid developer directory)